# Is there anything wrong with how I use the Copy-Item cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

So, I am trying to copy a users home folder with all of its subdirectories into a folder on my desktop called (username)_removed, but its saying "Copy-Item: Container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item."

Here is my code:

```
$names | foreach-object {Copy-Item -Path C:\Users\$_\* -Destination C:\Users\$user\Desktop\"$_"_removed -Recurse}
```

Comment: Change `C:\Users\$user\Desktop\"$_"_removed` to `C:\Users\$user\Desktop\${_}_removed` - assuming there's a `*_removed` folder already existing at the destop

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thanks!